# Compressing a string

Tags: string, compression

There is a frequently asked question in interviews about compressing a string.
I'm not looking for a code, I only need an efficient algorithm that solves the problem.

**Given a string (*e.g. aaabbccaaadd*), compress it (*3a2b2c3a2d*).**

My solution:

> Travel on the string. Every time I see the same letter I count it.
>   I will output the letter and the counter when I see a different letter coming (and start over again).

Is there more efficient way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: @Wug - Huffman Encoding wouldn't give the result specified in the question.

Comment: Are you asking for a good compression algorithm, or for an algorithm to produce a specific compression (the running length encoding, which is what your example output is)?

Comment: @delnan For the specific compression.. That's why I didn't use Huffman.

Comment: What happens if the string contains a number?

Comment: @IliaJerebtsov You can ignore numbers or assume there won't be.

Comment: Your result is wrong.  It should be ___3a2b2c3a2d___.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's called running length encoding, and the algorithm you name is basically the best you'll get. It takes O(1) auxiliary storage (save the last symbol seen, or equivalently inspect the upcoming element; also save a counter of how many identical symbols you've seen) and runs in O(n) time. As you need to inspect each symbol at least once to know the result, you can't get better than O(n) time anyway. What's more, it can also process streams one symbol at a time, and output one symbol at a time, so you actually only need O(1) RAM.

You can pull a number of tricks to get the constant factors better, but the algorithm remains basically the same. Such tricks include:

- If you stream to a slow destination (like disk or network), buffer. Extensively.
- If you expect long runs of identical symbols, you may be able to vectorize the loop counting them, or at least make that loop tighter by moving out the other cases.
- If applicable, tell your compiler not to worry about aliasing between input and output pointers.

Such micro-optimizations may be moot if your data source is slow. For the level of optimization some of my points above address, even RAM can counts as slow.

Answer (score 1):

Use Lempel Ziv compression if your string will be sufficiently long.. The advantage is: it will not only shorten distinct repetitions but also 'groups' of repetitions efficiently. See [wikipedia: Lempel-Ziv-Welch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel%E2%80%93Ziv%E2%80%93Welch)

A vague example - so that you get the idea:
aaabqxyzaaatuoiaaabhaaabi will be compressed as:
`A`bqxyz`A`tui`B`h`B`i
where [`A` = aaa] & [`B` = `A`b = aaab]

Answer (score 0):

many compression algorithms are based on [Huffman Coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding).  That's the answer I'd give in an interview

Comment: They are? The algorithms used in today's widely spread archives seem to be significantly different beasts.

Comment: If you told me that in an interview I'd still look at you confused. Again, AFAIK all of the most widely used compression algorithms are unrelated to it, and while there are a few variants of Huffman Coding and it's a great example for learning (it's seriously enlightening and I enjoyed dissecting it), it's basically just a small family in a huge tree of compression algorithms.